# How to convert a negative number to base in Java

Tags: java, radix

I have a negative integer `n` does anyone know can I convert to a base P in Java ?

Let's say `n= -31246` how to convert it to base 4 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
Integer.toString(-31246, 4)
```

Comment: and if it is a BigInteger ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Integer.toString,

```
Integer.toString(i, 4);
```

From the documentation,

```
public static String toString(int i, int radix)
```

> Returns a string representation of the first argument in the radix specified by the second argument. If the radix
>   is smaller than Character.MIN_RADIX or larger than
>   Character.MAX_RADIX, then the radix 10 is used instead.
>
> If the first argument is negative, the first element of the result is
>   the ASCII minus character '-' ('\u002D'). If the first argument is not
>   negative, no sign character appears in the result.
>
> The remaining characters of the result represent the magnitude of the
>   first argument. If the magnitude is zero, it is represented by a
>   single zero character '0' ('\u0030'); otherwise, the first character
>   of the representation of the magnitude will not be the zero character.
>   The following ASCII characters are used as digits: